# "Null" value in Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm trying to run code that will copy fields into a new table, moving them from a `_New` table to the original table.  The VBA code that does this works as such:

```
SQLStatement = CStr("INSERT INTO " & TName & " SELECT * FROM " & TName & "_New")
Log.WriteLine "Running query with string """ & SQLStatement & """ "
QueryTimer = Timer
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStatement
Log.WriteLine "Query time: " & (Timer - QueryTimer)
```

The log is just a handful of procedures in a class module I threw together.  Its output on the error is

```
@142921:  Running query with string "INSERT INTO Records SELECT * FROM Records_New" 
@142941:  Error Date/Time: 7/21/2009 2:29:40 PM
@142941:  Error # & Description: 3162, You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type.
```

I can confirm that `TName` and `SQLStatement` are both valid strings at the time the SQL operation is run, and that the sources (Records and Records_New) are both valid.  `Option Explicit` is set elsewhere in the file to avoid any confusion from typos.  The error is thrown on the `DoCmd` line.

Why would this have a `Null` value, even though `DoCmd.RunSQL` doesn't return a value?

Comment: What line is it throwing the error on?
Can you try adding "option explicit" to the top of your code and see if it still compiles?

Comment: Added information to answer your questions.

Comment: Did you try running the query directly (outside of your code). It might shed some light on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you post the table descriptions for Records and Records_New tables?
I would wager that you are trying to insert a NULL value into one of the columns of the "Records" table (and the column description is NOT NULL).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This turned out to be the issue.  The source (Records_New) was a stored Access Query that contained all the records in a table that did not exist in the Records table (based on Records having a `Null` ID auto number).  The `INSERT` tried to apply a `Null` auto number, which isn't allowed.  Hiding the result of the ID number check fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will help if you also change the insert statement to be more specific about which columns it is inserting/selecting. You are asking for bugs by being so non-specific.

This may seem like it is non-responsive to your answer, but I suspect that the columns in the select table and destination table are either not lined up, or there is a field in the destination table that disallows null.

Try this:

In a new Query (in SQL view) paste your query "INSERT INTO Records SELECT * FROM Records_New" in and try to run it manually. I bet you get a more specific error and can troubleshoot the query there before running it with the added complexity of the code around it.

Comment: Pasting in the SQL query gives an error dialog with the same message that was trapped in the code.  The help on this error doesn't provide any explanation, since I can't figure out what's been set to `Null` in the first place.

Comment: In that case, I suggest rewriting the the query to be more explicit about the exact fields in the source and destination table. Also double/triple check that none of the fields in the destination table disallow nulls, and that the field types are the same in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

[INSERT INTO Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861.aspx)

Your SQL INSERT statement is incorrect - it should be:

```
INSERT INTO Records SELECT * FROM [Records_New];
```

Here's what you need to use:

```
CStr("INSERT INTO " & TName & " SELECT * FROM [" & TName & "_New)"];")
```

Comment: What are the `n`s for?  I've never seen that in SQL syntax before?

Comment: It's a table alias, so you know you're getting * from the RECORDS_NEW table without concern that it might take from RECORDS instead or as well.

Comment: Your syntax gives a new error: `@151343:  Error # & Description: 3075, Syntax error in query expression 'SELECT n.* FROM Records_New n'.`

Comment: Try without the table alias - it's a force of habit, sorry.

Comment: Using `VALUES` here won't help, since its only for a single-record `INSERT`.  `VALUES` expects a list of values, one for each field, not a list of records like the `SELECT` would return.

Comment: You're right about the use of VALUES - I updated my post to include the MS Access 2007 MSDN link explaining its use.

Comment: KB article for my previous comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Timer needs parens?

```
QueryTimer = Timer()
```

Comment: `Timer` is a VBA builtin that returns fractions of a second since 1/1/1970.  Its used in other places without issue.  The iffy line is the `DoCmd.RunSQL` line.

Comment: Timer Function: "Returns a Single representing the number of seconds elapsed since midnight...In Microsoft Windows the Timer function returns fractional portions of a second" (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012289231033.aspx) Note it can be used as a expression in a Access database engine query.